# How to Display Columns for a Row that has a Condition

Tags: r

I loaded the MASS library and am trying to use the which.max() function to find the neighborhood with the highest median value which is a variable in Boston. I want to display the row that has the highest value but only columns 1,6,13,14.

```
which.max(df$medv)
```

^This gives me the max but how do I display those columns for the max row?

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the required columns.

```
res <- df[which.max(df$medv), c(1,6,13,14)]
res
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset`

```
res <-  subset(df, medv == max(medv), select = c(1, 6, 13, 14))
```